# getting error "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

Tags: react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I am trying to dispatch some actions with redux saga but getting error

```
function fetchCreationsRequest (requestPayload) {
    debugger
    return {
        type: FETCH_CREATIONS_LOADING,
        requestPayload
    }
}

export function fetchCreations (requestPayload = {}) {
    debugger
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchCreationsRequest(requestPayload))
    }
}
```

"fetchCreations" function executes perfect but when "fetchCreationsRequest" action dispatch i am getting this error
"Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."
Any suggestion about this?

Comment: are you using redux-thunk middleware while creating store

Comment: no i am using saga middleware "createSagaMiddleware" for creating middleware.

Comment: the syntax that you use is related to redux-thunk whereas redux-saga works using yield. I think you need to change your syntax to something supported by redux-saga

Comment: yield is used is sagas but i am currently dispatching an action this produces an error without going into saga.

Comment: `return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(fetchCreationsRequest(requestPayload))
       }
   }` in order to use this syntax you would need to use redux-thunk. Otherwise directly dispatch the relevant action from react component

Comment: this syntax is working fine in my other project with redux saga.